# Algorithm of Blender's Proportional Editing- verts outside radius

Tags: mesh, transforms

Hi anyone knows why vertices outside the radius get influenced too during proportional editing? The .gif is in right ortho with smooth falloff. Note: Verts outside the radius are the bottom left vert connects to 5654, the vert on the right of 5887,the vert on the right of 5881, the vert on top of 5827, the vert on top of 5928.

[image]

Comment: A single vert selection only shifts other verts within the radius  It is only by choice that your selection in image is within the radius.  Suggest the radius of influence applies from each vert.  Simple test on grid eg select two verts outside circle, appears to confirm this.

Comment: @batFINGER The bottom left vert connects to 5654, the vert on the right of 5887,the vert on the right of 5881, the vert on top of 5827. Those are outside the radius but  transformed in proportional edit.

Comment: Suggesting in your mind draw the radius around each of all selected verts .. that  is the area of influence.. Eg select two verts that are that far apart neither are in the circle and see what it does.

Comment: @batFINGER 1. The radius is already shown in the .gif. 2. Your suggestion is an extreme case. If you select two verts not too far apart from circle and see what it does, you'll likely get the same thing as the .gif.

Comment: What you will get is that verts within the radius of each will move. It is not a global only verts in the circle move. Its an indicator of how far from each vert selected is influenced.

Comment: @batFINGER Hold on, are you saying the radius is the radius for each selected vertex? So blender is only showing one circle to simplify the visualization?

Comment: Yes!!!! ended up answering to explain lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The radius displayed is an indicator of influence from each of all selected.**

[image]

A single vert selection only shifts other verts within the radius  Suggest the radius of influence applies from each vert.

Simple test on grid eg select two verts outside circle, appears to confirm this.

Notice with two verts selected on grid, both outside the displayed radius of influence, move verts of within the radius of influence of each.

Each vert that moves is within the radius distance of a selected vert.

In your question image no vert is being moved that is not within the radius of another selected vert.

Comment: ok now it raises another question. For vert within multiple radius, how does it determine which radius does it belong? Or is there some math behind it that it has the same distance to all radius it falls into? https://imgur.com/a/rLQODfE